# Delete all music NOT in playlist?

Tags: music, files, delete

I have a playlist of favorite music on my phone. It's time I got I'm of all the others that I regularly skip and never listen to.

How can I select all music that is NOT in that playlist in order yo manipulate it?

Comment: A shell script might prove helpful here (run either from a terminal emulator or via ADB): Collect all your music files, extract the file names from your playlist, match them, and then take the appropriate actions. I don't know of any ready-to-go solution to be used instead.